# How do I clone a larger drive on to a smaller one

Tags: hard-drive, cloning, easeus-todo-backup

Can Todo Backup clone from a 500 GB hard drive to a 120 GB? The 500 contains the OS plus 15 applications. The 120 is empty. A second 120 only contains the OS. I can clone using either.

Todo says the target needs to be equal or larger than master. Since the 500 FREE space should be less than 120 I cannot believe this is true.

Comment: Are the contents of the 500 larger than 120 GB?

Answer (score 1):

It might be trying to clone the entire partition, which would require the drive to be the same size or larger to avoid shrinking partitions and potentially messing with the data.

I did a bit of research, the only software I could find that might allow this is [ShadowCopy](http://www.runtime.org/shadow-copy.htm) - it doesn't specifically say if it does or not on the website.

If it doesn't, you may have to shrink the partition on your 500GB down to 120GB, and then try to image it from there. You'll want to use something like a Gparted live boot, you can use [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create the bootable flash drive.